# Работа скрипта только в активном окне браузера

Tags: javascript

Как заставить данный цикл работать только тогда, когда у пользователя активно окно браузера.
То есть, цикл должен переставать работать, когда окно браузера свёрнуто или когда пользователь перешел на другую вкладку браузера(на другой сайт).

```js
let a = document.querySelector('.opa');

let go = setInterval(function() {
  a.style.height = a.offsetHeight * 1 + 'px';
}, 1000);
```

```css
.opa {
  padding: 20px;
  background: gray;
}
```

```html
<div class="opa"> Это цикл </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте воспользоваться Page Visibility API. Возможно вам этого будет достаточно. Для этого надо подписаться на ивент visibilitychange.

```js
let a = document.querySelector('.opa');
let interval;

function startDoingSothing() {
  interval = setInterval(function() {
    a.style.height = a.offsetHeight * 1 + 'px';
  }, 1000);
}

startDoingSothing();

function handleVisibilityChange() {
  console.log( document.visibilityState );
  if (document.visibilityState === "hidden") {
    clearInterval(interval);
  } else {
    startDoingSothing();
  }
}

document.addEventListener("visibilitychange", handleVisibilityChange, false);
```

```css
.opa {
  padding: 20px;
  background: gray;
}
```

```html
<div class="opa"> Это цикл </div>
```

Comment: Вот это чудеса, а где можно подробно прочитать про это волшебство?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Page_Visibility_API

Comment: Кстати обратите еще внимание на ивенты onblur и onfocus. Они уведомляют, что пользователь переключил окна (но страница может быть не скрыта)

Comment: Но в вашем коде нет таких ивентов, почему?

Comment: Я не знаю что именно вы делаете и не знаю нужны ли вам эти ивенты. Просто предложил взглянуть и на них.